# C - (malloc, calloc, or static) 2d char array returned from function

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, static, malloc

I've been on the site for hours now and I read a lot of new techniques and programmed defined functions,but I'm still a little confused on how to apply it to my own program. I trying to start slow and build a checkers game. So first I created a function to create a Board. Of course i researched and read that C doesn't easily allow for you to return char arrays from functions. So I read up on memory allocation using malloc or calloc.

So my first mistake...

```
void printBoard(char arr[9][19]);
int makeMove(char arr[11][23], int king, struct player P, char player);
char *createBoard();

char Rows[8]="ABCDEFGH";

int main()
{
    int x, y;
    int isKing = 1;
    char checkerBoard[9][19];

    checkerBoard[9][19] = createBoard();
    printBoard(checkerBoard);
    /* ... */
}
```

and then...

```
void printBoard(char array[9][19])
{

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 19; j++)
            printf("%c", array[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
};

char * createBoard()
{
    // where I put code

    return  checkerBoard[9][19];
}
```

I purposely left out the code inside createBoard() it was a lot. So when using void *malloc(size_t size), I know i need to specify the bytes in size like 4 * sizeof(char)but doesn't the size the array go in there also? Also, would changing the checkerBoard array to static be better?

Comment: `4 * sizeof(char)` is the same as `4 * 1`. `char Rows[8]="ABCDEFGH";` You have no room for `'\0'`

Comment: Try to understand [This DEMO](https://ideone.com/loPmlh)

Comment: Is the question not clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its great that you are reading about arrays in C. You mentioned in your question that you read that "C doesn't allow you to easily return arrays from functions". In C, when you declare a statically sized array inside of a function, that array in memory exists on the stack. Every function has it's own stack, so when you return from a function, that memory can be reused again.

When you allocate space with malloc and calloc, that allocates space on the heap. Here is an article with more information: [Stack Vs Heap](http://net-informations.com/faq/net/stack-heap.htm).

Now onto your checkerboard issue, what you want is an array of arrays. You can think of each square on the checkerboard as being an individual character. Let's say our checkerboard had one row.

```
char * row_zero = malloc(sizeof(char) * 15); //row_zero has a length of 15
```

Checkerboards obviously have more than one row though, what about 9?

```
char * row_zero = malloc(sizeof(char) * 15);
char * row_one = malloc(sizeof(char) * 15);
.
.
char * row_eight = malloc(sizeof(char) * 15);
```

While you can do this, it will be incredibly messy. So instead of creating individual rows, you can simply have a **pointer to an array of pointers**.

```
char ** my_checkerboard = malloc(sizeof(char*) * 9); //has 9 rows.
```

I will let you figure out how to finish making your board.

Comment: So how would one of the rows be accessed or modified? @Carson

Comment: The checkerboard above is an array of char *. Indexing into the checkerboard will give you a char *, which you can also index into.

Comment: @Carmon than you for the insight, I have allocated the memory for the array and have found out how to access and modify elements.